# Apache is trying to access to files as folders

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, directory

I am running Apache 2.2.22 in Debian with this `.htaccess` in the site root: file

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -Indexes -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

#Redirect without www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

#Allow access without .php extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

That's the main code and we also have a couple of `<FilesMatch>` instructions and some `mod_deflate` checks.

The issue is, we're checking this url:

`www.example.com/abc`

Which is just the `abc.php` file in the site root, so the server redirects as expected to `example.com/abc`.

But if I access to `(www.)example.com/abc/` the server just throw an HTTP 404 error, which is obvious because the directory `/abc/` does not exist.

Shouldn't those defined options avoid that? What may be the issue here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove a trailing slash using a redirect rule first:

```
# remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /$1 [NE,R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Nice! Works like a charm. Thank you. Is there any way to redirect to the same URL without the trailing slash?

Comment: That will require an additional redirect rule. See my updated answer.

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you very much!